# PC switches off or locks up

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, freeze

I have a PC that switches off or locks up. The switching off was happening frequently (several times a day) until the owner flushed out the dust with air. Now it still happens but less frequently (once a day) but it experiences lock-ups in Windows 10 and in the BIOS.

The system is

- Motherboard: MSI 970 Gaming
- CPU: AMD FX8350 8 Core CPU
- Cooling: Radiator with large fan which is connected to the CPU
- PSU: RAIDMAX RX-850AE
- RAM: Passed when tested using W10 Diagnostics

In fact the last lockup happened when I was looking at the BIOS settings and I had to press the reset button to recover. The CPU was a cool 36C as reported in BIOS so it was not overheated and since the power did not cut out, I am leaning towards the Motherboard being at fault.

[image]

Before I go out and get a replacement MB, what do you guys think?

---

EDIT: It just switched off again. Had OpenHardwareMonitor running and logging but I guess the data was not flushed to disk since there is a gap of about 30 minutes... Turned write caching off so hopefully it will catch more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close inspection of the motherboard revealed that a spare, loose, 4-pin LP4 female connector connected to a cooling fan, was sitting on top of a metallic component of the motherboard.

I used some tape to keep it away from the motherboard components and now, nearly a week later, the owner has not had any issues at all!